# Sunspot Solr - manually set semantic equalities for searches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Sunspot_solr in my rails application and I've applied it to searching for local businesses by address.

My question is, how could I define that "parkway" and "pkwy" are semantically the same so that a user searching for "pkwy" in the street address still returns the same results as if they had used "parkway" instead?

There are obviously a number of these types of equalities and I want to be able to define a set of them somewhere to allow users more flexibility when doing their search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration directory, where `schema.xml` is, you can add to or create a `synonyms.txt` file that maps words to alternate spellings/synonyms. `sunspot_solr` should have already created this file for you in your rails app.

You would have an entry like this:

```
parkway => pkwy
```

In `schema.xml`, you will need to add a [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) during your indexing and/or query step.

Read the link above for more information.